# PHP separate domain and subdomain url from file upload

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert this address to MySQL database:

```
http://localhost/user/uploads/files/1/avatar/Dave.jpg
```

I need to separate domain (localhost) and subdomain (if found) from this URL like this:

```
uploads/files/1/avatar/Dave.jpg
```

how do I separate them?

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://localhost.com/user/uploads/files/1/avatar/Dave.jpg';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed['path'];

echo $path; //gives user/uploads/files/1/avatar/Dave.jpg
```

Works for subdomains too. You can just str_replace `/user/` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/user/uploads/files/1/avatar/Dave.jpg';
$url = preg_replace('/http:\/\/((.*)?localhost)\/user\//', '',  $url);
```

If you want to replace ANY host (and not just localhost or subdomains of it), use this instead:

```
$url = preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*)\/user\//', '',  $url);
```

In fact I see no reason why you can't use that anyway.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: oops missed the subdomain bit, updated